# How to get the Sum of values from a SQLite Table?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm trying to Collect Bids and Distribute the average from a Column

I'm getting an InvalidCast Exception: Specified cast is not valid. on the TotalSum +=

Any Help would be greatly apprciated

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT " & Column & " FROM " & Table & " ;"
Dim dt As DataTable = SQLiteDatabase.GetDataTable(sql)
Column = Column.Replace("[", "")
Column = Column.Replace("]", "")
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    TotalSum += DirectCast(row(Column), Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Calculating TotalSum {0}", TotalSum.ToString)
Next row
```

Comment: 1. Is your TotalSum an integer? 2. Check every row in dt and make sure that column is an integer column

Comment: on the first line there was a dbNull. It wasn't in the table

Comment: Yes, that's where the error coming from. you can put a try catch block to skip that record like your answer, but checking the reason of the null value would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Solution is this

```
Dim suma As Double = 0.0R
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim num As Double = 0R
    Double.TryParse(row(Column).ToString, num)
    suma += num
Next row
```

Columns could potentually contain Stings in my application since the User can input SQL directly. I'm only working with Double types but Integers are an option

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
int suma = 0;

Dim dc as DataColumn = dt.Columns[0]  //Column to add
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
          suma += int.Parse(row[dc])
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Good Replies

My Fix is

```
    Try
        TotalSum += Convert.ToInt32(row(Column))
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating TotalSum {0}", TotalSum.ToString)
    Catch
    End Try
```

Try Catch Block added to watch for vbNull. I just want Value Higher then 0